# returning DOM obj using getElementByID

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var vehicleType = document.getElementById('Vehicle_Type');
var obj = vehicleType;
var objVal = obj.value;
var node = obj.parentNode;
```

I believe there's some problem with obj.value....is there any way where i can get the DOM object of the element on the page called 'Vehicle Type'?

Danke,

Comment: `vehicleType` *is* the element. What kind of element is this?

Comment: Yep, `getElementById` is the way to do it, but not every DOM element has a `value` property. What kind of element is `#Vehicle_Type` and which data do you want to get with `vehicleType.value`? Or what exactly do you mean by *"element [...] **called** 'Vehicle Type'"*? If the element does not have the **ID** `Vehicle_Type`, `getElementById` of course does not help.

Comment: Works fine for me, perhaps the element with that id does not exist in the DOM. http://jsfiddle.net/TrgR3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `vehicleType` and `obj` reference the actual DOM element, however the call to `.value` may not be appropriate.

Depending on what type of element this is, you may not actually have a `.value` property. The `.value` property is generally found on various form elements.

If you're wanting to get the text contents of the element, you should instead try `.textContent` or `.innerText` instead.

Additionally, make sure you have your elements' id attribute set properly. If you're running the following:

```
document.getElementById('Vehicle_Type')
```

This will look for an element having the attribute `id='Vehicle_Type'`.